# On SSRS Report Server, how to read user permissions

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

I've searched a couple places for this but haven't found a solution that would meet my needs. I currently develop a web application that also provides direct access to a reporting services server hosting SSRS reports. I am able to pass credentials created for the application that has admin privileges to the folders so it can pull together a list of the different reports. What I need to be able to do is have it check to see if the logged in user has the correct privileges to the report that they're viewing. I would prefer not to manage this in the application as I don't maintain the SSRS reports. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Both the application and the Reporting services are contained in the intranet for the company and is not accessible outside so we are using NT authentication on both. My application checks the LDAP to validate active users only have access. I just need to be able to match the NT Login I receive with the list on the Report Server.

Comment: How are you querying the list of reports -- SSRS WebService or direct table access?

Comment: I am accessing it through the webservice

Comment: There is the `GetPolicies()` method on the webservice.  The problem is that I think you are likely to have some of the policies set up with AD groups rather than discrete user names.  I don't have a machine available at the moment with an SSRS instance so I cannot test.  If you manage to get some results from `GetPolicies()` and it has AD groups in it, this post may help for determining whether a particular user is a member of a particular AD group: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029378/how-to-check-if-a-user-belongs-to-an-ad-group

Comment: Thanks, I was able to verify the AD group via the LDAP memberOf lists.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. #SOReadyToHelp