# WindowsIdentity - Difference between Groups and Claims

Tags: c#, .net, windows-identity

I'm trying to check whether the User belongs to some groups by using SID-s.

I was using [WindowsIdentity.Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.groups?view=net-5.0), but then noticed that sometimes it doesn't show that the user belongs to the Administrators group.

After searching a while, I've discovered that instead [WindowsIdentity.Claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.claims?view=net-5.0) work fine (includes the admin group in the results as well).
I wasn't able to find proper documentation on [Claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.claims?view=net-5.0).

So, what is the difference between the Groups and Claims in WindowsIdentity, and why groups don't show administrators group while the Claims do?
And finally, can I safely use Claims instead of Groups?

Here's the code I have:

```
var wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

var sidToFind = "S-1-5-32-544"; // Hardcoded the sid of administrators group for demo, but in general this is a parameter of a function on my side

// This will NOT include the sid S-1-5-32-544
var groupSids= wi.Groups
    .Where(item => item.Value == sidToFind);

// This will include the sid S-1-5-32-544 and also all the other results that Groups provides.
var claimSids = wi.Claims
    .Where(item => item.Value == sidToFind));
```

Comment: If you wants to check specific user belongs to some groups by SIDs, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536043/how-can-i-securely-ensure-the-current-user-belongs-to-an-active-directory-group?noredirect=1&lq=1) would help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are differencies between groups and claims.

- Groups work with WORKGROUP and AD
- Claims work with Active Directory Federation Services

Claims is more complex way to check user identity, because claims exists not only for ADFS, you can use or create additional [claims token provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

When we call Groups method for WindowsIdentity, we have restriction:

> // [Ignore disabled, logon ID, and deny-only groups.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/principal/windowsidentity.cs)

[The role of claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/technical-reference/the-role-of-claims)

> In the claims-based identity model, claims play a pivotal role in the
> federation process, They are the key component by which the outcome of
> all Web-based authentication and authorization requests are
> determined. This model enables organizations to securely project
> digital identity and entitlement rights, or claims, across security
> and enterprise boundaries in a standardized way.

So, if you work only in NTLM - you can safty work with Groups, but if you want work via federation (for example SharePoint, Google, etc) - you must use claims. Claims contains groups, but groups not contain claims.

In order to answer the question why you do not see a certain group, you need to know its properties and location. As I wrote above and gave the link, there are restrictions on getting the list of groups. But [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/security-identifiers-in-windows) i found this info:

| SID | Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S-1-5-32-544 | Administrators | A built-in group. After the initial installation of the operating system, the only member of the group is the Administrator account. When a computer joins a domain, the Domain Admins group is added to the Administrators group. When a server becomes a domain controller, the Enterprise Admins group also is added to the Administrators group. |

So, if your local admins group is disabled - you cannot see it when you get it via WindowsIdentity even if the user is included in it.